# Conditional Merging in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe of one column containing just names:

```
Names
Matthew
Mark
Luke
John
```

I also have around 10 files that contain more data and also have a name column, one such file is:

```
Names    Sum    Random_data
Matthew   200     x
James     400     y
some_guy  150     x
Wilson    500     y
```

while another file can have:

```
Names    Sum    Random_data
Luke      800     x
Bart      700     y
Sean      250     x
TOast     100     y
```

I want the values of the 'Sum' column from each of the 10 files to be merged into the relative row in the first file as a new column. I imagine this can be done by looping through all the files I want to search for the correct 'Name' row in and then performing a merge on both files as dataframes:

```
for data_file in all_files_that_have_data:

        data_df = pd.read_csv(data_file)
        df = df.merge(data_df, on='Name', how='left', suffixes=['','_remove'])
        cols = [c for c in df.columns if '_remove' not in c]
        df = df[cols]
        print(df.columns)
```

My question is how can I do this without overwriting the data each time I perform a merge. The correct data for a Name could be in one file, but would be lost upon merging with the next file. Is there way to conditionally merge each file but only overwrite if the left dataframe row's current value is NaN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you get only unique values from your csv files, why not creating a single dataframe containing all the values from your csv files and then merging?

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame()

for data_file in all_files_that_have_data:
    data_df_temp = pd.read_csv(cpc_file)
    data_df = data_df.append(data_df_temp)

df = df.merge(data_df, on='Names', how='left')
print(df.columns)
```

Comment: This did the job! All I had to do then was just filter out the columns I did not need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) ([`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)):

```
#create list of all DataFrames from csvs
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fp) for fp in all_files_that_have_data]
#concanecate them together
df_all = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
#left join
df = pd.merge(df, df_all, how='left')
#alternatively
#df = df.join(df_all.set_index('Names'), on='Names')
print (df)
     Names    Sum Random_data
0  Matthew  200.0           x
1     Mark    NaN         NaN
2     Luke  800.0           x
3     John    NaN         NaN
```